# How to take this element in URL

Tags: php, url

I need in this url boutique/index.php?Products&Featured to take element like Products&Featured for example

this code is important

```
// $mb->pages has Products&Featured

(in_array($PHP_SELF , explode(';' , $mb->pages)
```

but $PHP_SELF send index.php and I need the elements after index.php

An idea ?

If I have this in this moment :

Thank.

```
        if ( class_exists($class) ) {
                    $mb = new $class();
// dynamic template
                    if(!isset($mb->pages) && ($mb->isEnabled())){
                      $this->pages = 'all';
                      $mb->execute();
                    } else {
                      if(($mb->isEnabled()) && (($mb->pages === 'all') || (in_array($PHP_SELF , explode(';' , $mb->pages))))) {
                        $mb->execute();
                      }
                    }
// eof Dynamic Template
                  }
```

Solution after suggestion

```
          if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) {
             if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) {
                if(($mb->isEnabled()) && (isset($mb->pages) === 'all') || ( (in_array($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] , explode(';' , $mb->pages) ) ) ))   {
                  $mb->execute();
                }
              } else  {
                //var_dump($PHP_SELF , explode(';' , $mb->pages));

                if(($mb->isEnabled()) && (isset($mb->pages) === 'all') || ( (in_array($PHP_SELF , explode(';' , $mb->pages) ) ) ))   {
                  $mb->execute();
                }
          }
```

Comment: Have you tried `parse_url()`

Comment: You want `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` not `$PHP_SELF`.

Comment: Also, if you want the literal & you will need to use `urlencode()` to contruct the link.

Comment: thank I forget this $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], works.

Comment: Just curious - why do none of the answers mention `$_GET[]`?

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] (see above) : ok I use this, just a question, if my url is rewrited, the code will be always functionnal ?

Answer (score 0):

Take ['query'] part of `parse_url`

```
print_r(parse_url('boutique/index.php?Products&Featured'));

Array
(
    [path] => boutique/index.php
    [query] => Products&Featured
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'boutique/index.php?Products&Featured';
$urlArray = parse_url($url);

echo $urlArray['query'];
```

Comment: It's `$urlArray['query']`, not `$urlArray('query')`